# How could "this character" come back to life without becoming a Vampire at the end of Stardust Crusaders?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

At the end of JoJo season 3: [Stardust Crusaders,](http://jojo.wikia.com/wiki/Stardust_Crusaders) episode 48:

> Dio Brando killed Joseph Joestar using 'The World'. Later on, Dio drained his blood entirely and left Joseph Joestar as a husk.

However, Jotaro was able to revive

> Joseph by transferring blood from Dio's dead body into his Grand Dad. ([YouTube reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jh-H4Dwv5GQ))

**What I'm trying to understand though is why**

> **Joseph did not turn into an undead vampire**.

Because I remember the episode before that, Dio had previously used his blood

> to turn [Vanilla Ice](http://jojo.wikia.com/wiki/Vanilla_Ice) into a vampire (the one with the "self-eating" Stand).

Answer (score 4):

No hard facts are given on this one (at least none translated that I was able to find).

But a common theory is Hamon.  Joseph was a naturally gifted Hamon user.  So the theory is that the blood started to turn Joseph into a vampire, but his natural Hamon purified it at the same time, so he was restored to life as a normal human (or as normal as Joestar can ever be).

Also, DIO had only consumed Joseph's blood an hour earlier, so the blood may have still counted more as Joseph's than anything else.

But most importantly, Jojos in general runs on Rule of Cool and Rule of Funny.  You shouldn't try to apply to much logic to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to the fact Dio was dead and utterly destroyed, the blood was just "normal" blood without any immortal vampiric properties. Plus it is technically not Dio's blood but Jonathan Joestar's.

It is only my theory.

Comment: Jonathan's body was completely taken over by Dio and over the years it became Dio's body. Remember at first, Dio was having trouble healing his scar on his neck because the body was rejecting him, but after a couple years he completely healed and at that point he completely took over Jonathans Body. So it was in fact DIo's blood

Answer (score 1):

DIO's head was destroyed so the thing that was making Jonathan's body Vampirish effect was gone except for the weakness to the sun part. The blood will disappear when in contact with the sun. So if a jojo got some of the blood, some of their blood will evaporate in the sun. Also Joseph was not reduced to a husk, a cup of blood can't drain a whole human. It's just that too much blood was lost to the point where he couldn't keep consciousness and soon would die of blood loss.